# How can I remove tooltips that appear when writing code in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I have these tooltips with method description appear when writing code in Visual Studio Code.
They also don't let me navigate around with the keyboard and cover some parts of code.

[image: 1]

They are very annoying and distracting. How can I remove them?